# Машинное обучение LDA, классификация текстов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, классификация-текста

мне необходимо классифицировать тексты( новости) по степени важности РФ. 1 категория - угроза НБ(ключ фразы: терроризм, ядерное оружие итд) 2 категория - страны СНГ (ключ слова названия стран ) 3 категория НАТО G7 и тд. По стандартному методу, ты посылаешь набор текстов, создаешь модель LDA, определяешь количество тем, на которое надо разбить эти тексты. И LDA создает список тем, к которым относит отдельные слова из тех текстов с весом важности!. Вот мне надо самому своими руками создать так список слов с весом важности и потом по нему обучать программу, а не наоборот. Кто знает, как сделать, пожалуйста подскажите, или если кто знает другой способ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот на рисунке в нижней строке и есть тот список, который мне надо самому заполнить. Но имею мало опыта, и не могу понять, как его заполнить самому, без поставки набора текстов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй https://guidedlda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Там можно задать сиды - слова, по которым будут собираться темы.